# What's is the efficient way to implement admob ads on multiple activities?

Tags: android, admob

I am creating an app and it contain 20 different activities. I have implemented admob banner ads on Mainactivity and want to implements these on the other activities. Is there any efficient way to implements ads at a time rather than implementing them one by one on each activity. Below is my code. Thanks

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AdView mAdView;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AdView adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");

        MobileAds.initialize(this, initializationStatus -> {
        });

        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the same ads at the multiple screens in your app, I think you'd rather use one activity with multiple [fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments). Since you already made all of the app, I think it's better to put the admob banner code one by one.

By the way it's not good to upload id via online. So it's better to remove the id, which is `adView.setAdUnitId("this code");`